# Nested Select in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying the 5th question in the Nested Select of SQL zoo (using Oracle engine) http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

> Show the name and the population of each country in Europe. Show the
>   population as a percentage of the population of Germany.

I know the correct answer (given below), but something puzzled me.

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(ROUND(population/(SELECT population
    FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany'),2)*100,'%')
FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

When I run the following modified query, only one row (Albania) is returned.

```
SELECT name, population/(SELECT population
    FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')
FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Wondering if anyone can shed light on the inner workings of Oracle as to why only Albania is returned? Its puzzling to me why it doesn't work without ROUND().

Comment: Work fine for me..

Comment: When I put in your second query into the webpage you provided under question 5, it returns plenty of results for me.

Comment: Yes, running your exact query returns many European countries for me too.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is actually:

```
SELECT name, 
       CONCAT(ROUND(population/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')*100,0),'%') 
FROM world 
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Note the results set rounds to zero decimal spaces.

That said, I tried your exact code above and still get results for all countries:

```
SELECT name, 
       population/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')     
FROM world 
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

You're right to be puzzled as it should certainly return regardless of using `ROUND()` or not, but since I cannot recreate it, I can't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient Oracle query (that gets rid of the sub-query) is to use an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

```
SELECT name,
       ROUND(
         population
         / MAX( CASE name WHEN 'Germany' THEN population END ) OVER ()
         * 100
       ) || '%'
FROM   world;
```

However, sqlzoo appears to use MariaDB so you can't put that query into the website (but if you recreate the table in Oracle then you can test it).